# Add Surface Information alternatives in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, 3d-analyst

Is anyone aware of a single tool or possible routine of tools in QGIS (2.6) which emulate the results of the ESRI 3D Analyst tool 'Add Surface Information'? I have several polygon shapefiles (some with 1000+ features) I am trying to tag with information from a LiDAR-derived raster.

As a bare minimum, I am wanting to extract MIN and MAX elevations, but would also like to grab MEAN elevations and SLOPE information from the raster.

TO UPDATE: I've recently stumbled across the Zonal Statistics plugin which produces MEAN values for raster data within a set polygon(s). Am still searching for a plugin to generate SLOPE data.

Comment: There are a number of Slope-related tools in the [_Processing Toolbox_](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/139955/what-is-the-best-way-to-automate-the-gis-slope-and-aspect-algorithm/140104#140104) which might help.

Answer (score -1):

There is an alternative in QGIS, you must use SAGA´s tool "Add raster values to points"

Answer (score -1):

Point Sampling Tool try this one out i may work

---

Slight correction I found a work around you need statistical data right I don't to buffer the point and do zonal statistics and get all the informatics.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour].  Your answer is unclear - please [edit] your answer to include the steps required, and an explanation of what it does to answer the original question